# Group access to device using udev

Tags: linux, udev

Short question. Is it a good idea to give a group of users access to certain devices by writing your own udev rules in linux? If not, what would be a better approach?

I want the changes to be persistent and it is not sufficient to manage the permissions manually during runtime.

As an example, say that I want all the users in group 'serial' to be able to use serial usb devices.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that's a perfectly valid use for udev.